# Using SQL data as the data source for an Excel pivot table when the SQL uses an SQL Table Valued function

Tags: sql-server, excel, export-to-excel, table-valued-parameters

Using Microsoft Query I'm trying to setup a sql data source for an Excel pivot table, specifically when the sql contains a table valued function.  The sql shown in the picture below is how it successfully runs in SSMS.

I've used sql as a data source many times for an Excel pivot table, but never when the sql is using a table valued function as a table source.

I'm getting the following error when I try to add it as the data source for my excel connection.

[image: Error when using an SQL table value function in Excel]

Comment: I believe the Microsot Query tool also works with views. Have you tried wrapping the select code in a view? And don't use `select *`, list the specific column names returned from the UDF.

Comment: For what it's worth, using `OPTION (MAX RECURSION)` is a code smell that something is logically broken with the code.

Comment: @alwayslearning:  I actually trying to get away from using a view for what I'm using this for.

Answer (score 0):

When I returned to Excel from MS query I was able to update the sql there.  It then worked.